# Sqoop connecting between EMR and Netezza

Tags: sqoop, netezza, emr

We are not able to connect to Netezza from EMR via sqoop connection. Below is the error message. I am wondering if there is some port need to be open in Netezza host. Thanks.

```
./sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/bin/sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:netezza://<NETEZZA-HOST>/<NETEZZA-DB> --username XXXX --password XXXX

15/02/12 23:30:43 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.netezza.internal.NzSocket.sendChar(NzSocket.java:84)
at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.close(NzConnection.java:1187)
at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.initSocket(NzConnection.java:2673)
at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.open(NzConnection.java:260)
at org.netezza.datasource.NzDatasource.getConnection(NzDatasource.java:523)
at org.netezza.datasource.NzDatasource.getConnection(NzDatasource.java:510)
at org.netezza.Driver.connect(Driver.java:153)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:877)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.listTables(SqlManager.java:517)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Comment: Netezza does not listen on different ports for different clients.  All data connections to Netezza are on port 5480, which is the default port encoded in the jdbc driver.  If you can connect to netezza with a JDBC tool such as squirrel or dbvisualizer, then you sqoop would be no different.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help with the sqoop portion, but hopefully that helps you debug it a bit.